# how to determine if applicationCache has been approved in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, application-cache

Currently, when you try to use the application manifest by specifying it in the html tag:

Firefox will prompt you to allow it (yes/no/never again).

How can I check if that request has been approved/denied already?

Comment: I don't know if this solves your questin: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#application-cache-api

Comment: you can debug it [Blog Post](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firefox Preference => Choose Advanced tab => Network sub-tab.

Look at `Offline Web Content and User Data` section. Uncheck "Tell me when a website asks to store data for offline use" to turn on Firefox Prompt of Offline Use for all sites you visit.

If you want turn on this Firefox prompt for a specific site, you have 2 case:

1. If this site was allowed before, you can find and remove the site record in the box "The following websites are allowed ...". It will prompt again when you visit this site.
2. If this site was disallowed before, you just click "Exceptions..." button (on right side), then find and remove the site record in dialog "Offline Data".

Hope it's helpful for you.